# find Processing instruction by value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have processing instructions like

```
<?pi id="id1" someadditionaldata ?>
```

I want to find that processing instruction with name 'pi' and id 'id1' in a xml

Answer (score 0):

```
*//processing-instruction('pi')[contains(., concat('id="', 'id1', '"'))]
```

Comment: This is quite incorrect, unless you do not define some additional rules on the syntax of the data of the PI.

Comment: ok, character " means start attribute value only. I will control the validity of the processing instruction content

Comment: This isn't the only problem... Try to write on paper all the rules that define the syntax. If it helps, try to write a Regex for it. If it helps, see how a PI is defined in the W3C XML specification ...